# Angular Material Input not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, angular-material

I, am using Angular material reference from  https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview and example from https://stackblitz.com/angular/kopgoqmxvbdl?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html

I, have the same code as shown in the example. However, it is not working for me. I, am using angular 5 template in asp.net code 2.0.

In my index.cshtml page I, have added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
```

Here is the html code where input field are not working

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Input">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Select">
            <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

The same code from example.

Here is the **App.share.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import 'hammerjs';
import 'angular-polyfills';
import 'web-animations-js';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { EqualValidator } from "./components/Validation/equal.validator.directive";
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/usercreation/login.component';
import { MobileComponent } from './components/mobile/mobile.component';
import { SocialComponent } from './components/usercreation/social.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/usercreation/signup.component';
import { DashBoardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';

import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, RegisterComponent, EqualValidator, DashBoardComponent,
        HomeComponent, NavMenuComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        MobileComponent,
        SocialComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'mobile', component: MobileComponent },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashBoardComponent },
            { path: 'signup', component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

**Component Ts File**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from "../app/app.component";
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
})
export class DashBoardComponent {
    private _appComponent: AppComponent;
    constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent) {

        this._appComponent = appComponent;
        this._appComponent.menulist = true;


    }

}
```

**webpack.config.vendor.js**

```
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    '@angular/material',
    '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css',
    '@angular/cdk',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);
```

**Vendor.css**

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
.mdl-layout--fixed-header > .mdl-layout__header {
    z-index: 6;
}

.has-drawer .mdl-layout__drawer {
    padding-top: 64px;
}

.mdl-layout--fixed-drawer:not(.is-small-screen) > .mdl-layout__header {
    padding-left: 240px;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Getting an error as GET http://localhost:54236/dist/~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css net::ERR_ABORTED - The css file is not loaded.

Here is the output which I am getting from the code

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my vendor.css and vendor.js was not refresh. So, I need to build the webpack again using

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

If webpack is not install. Please install the webpack

```
npm install -g webpack
```

Inside webpack.config.vendor.js

```
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/material',
    '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css',
    '@angular/cdk',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are still missing out references there, which might explain why the input control seems broken with Angular Material.

Have you also added reference to this?

`<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>`

I think the script file should go with the css together.

You might also want to include this style as well.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">`

For more details, please check [this link](https://getmdl.io/started/index.html).

Comment: No this is not the reason. I, am using Angular material. I have included the <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script> but still no solution

Comment: Menu also not working for me..... Can you please let me know where I, am doing wrong

Comment: @SanJaisy perhaps try adding css directly in the style.css in your angular project as opposed to linking it in the html. `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';` This is the Angular Material pre-built theme.

Comment: I use the @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' but the css  file is not loaded. In node modules I have that file. In browser the file is not loaded

Comment: @SanJaisy I am not sure if this may be due to the use of Material Design Lite library you are using in the project. To me, you should not get an error like `dist/~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css` as it's supposed to get compiled together with the rest of your angular code. You could possibly try removing all references to the MDL and only focusing on the Angular Material Design.

Comment: I don't have anything related to MDL

Comment: @SanJaisy '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">', `<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>`? Remove these references from your html, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

U need to change styles.scss

Please, add `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";`

This theme works correctly with white background.